# Why cannot I read data from /dev/graphics/fb0?

Tags: android, screen, snapshot

I am using the emulator. So definitely I have the root permission.
I use command:

`adb pull /dev/graphics/fb0 d:/a`

and then use my program to read this file and generate a bmp. It is successful. But when I use pure java code to do this:

`Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c cat /dev/graphics/fb0");`

`process.waitFor();`

`InputStream is = process.getInputStream();`

`is.read(buffer, 0, width*height*2);`

The buffer can not get the correct data. All the data is 0, while the correct is 0xFF at the first several line.

Then I tried:

`adb shell`

`cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /sdcard/tmp`

The tmp file also got the correct data.
Why the pure java code failed? Is the way I used the Process class wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since the fb0 is a buffer file, it is an always-changing file, you should copy it to a certain ACCESSIBLE destination then read it with `FileInputStream`, easily having the correct data.

Like:

```
("cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /dev/myRawFrame.raw");

File CurrentRawFile = new File("/dev/myRawFrame.raw");
```

and you're done :)